# Finding expected value and variance of $X$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X = \dfrac {\dfrac{\sqrt{V_1} \rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}+U}{\sqrt V_2}$, where $V_1 \sim \chi^2 (n-1), V_2\sim \chi^2(n-2), U\sim \mathrm N(0, 1)$ and $V_1, V_2, U$ are independent, and$\rho$ is a constant such that $|\rho|<1$. Find $\mathbb E[X^2], \mathrm{Var}(X)$ when $n>4$.

Since $\mathrm{Var}(X)=\mathbb E[X^2]−(\mathbb E[X])^2$, I think we have to find $\mathbb E[X]$ too. However, the form of $X$ is so complicated that I have trouble finding the expected value. Does anyone have ideas?

Edit: I found $\mathbb E[X^2]= \dfrac{\rho^2}{1-\rho^2}\cdot \dfrac{n-2}{n-4}$ from the data in wikipedia, so I only have to find $\mathbb E[X]$ or $\mathrm {Var}(X)$.

To find $\mathbb E[X]$, I tried as follows:

$\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E\left[\dfrac {\dfrac{\sqrt{V_1} \rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}+U}{\sqrt V_2}\right] = \dfrac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \cdot \mathbb E\left[\sqrt\frac{V_1}{V_2}\right]$ since $\mathbb E\left[\frac{U}{\sqrt{V_2}}\right]=0$ by symmetry of t-distribution. However, I can't figure out how to proceed further.

Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**:

$$E\left(\frac{\sqrt{V_1}}{\sqrt{V_2}}\right) = E(\sqrt{V_1})E\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{V_2}}\right)$$

$$Z \sim \chi_{n} \implies f_{Z}(z) = \frac{z^{n-1}e^{-z^2/2}}{2^{n/2-1} \Gamma(n/2)},  \ \ z > 0$$

$$W = 1/Z \implies f_{W}(w) = \frac{w^{-(n+1)}e^{-1/(2w^2)}}{2^{n/2-1} \Gamma(n/2)}, \ \ w > 0$$

$$E(W) = \frac{2^{(n-1)/2-1} \Gamma((n-1)/2)}{2^{n/2-1} \Gamma(n/2)}$$

Finally,

> $$E(\sqrt{V_1})E(1/\sqrt{V_2}) = \frac{2^{1/2}\Gamma(n/2)}{\Gamma((n-1)/2)} \frac{\Gamma((n-3)/2)}{2^{1/2}\Gamma((n-2)/2)} = \frac{n/2-1}{(n-1)/2-1} = \frac{n-2}{n-3}$$